# How to populate loaded content before it's displayed?

Tags: jquery

I'm on `index.html`, I ajax `query.php` and get the result. Now how do I populate `block.html` before loading it into `content` so that the text does not appear without the color/size information first?

**index.html**

```
<div id="content"><button id="button1" type="button">click</button></div>
```

**block.html**

```
You selected the color: <div id="color"></div>!
You chose a size of: <div id="size"></div>!
```

**query.php**

```
$result = array('color' => 'blue', 'size' => '12');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Why is block.html its own file?

Comment: There are multiple steps, when you click one button, it will load block.html into content, when you click another it will load block2.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some data and you have some HTML and you need to merge them together in a reasonable way. You're basically doing [client-side templating](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).

Here's one basic approach:

1. `$.get` the HTML you need and convert to a jQuery object `processBlock()`
2. `$.get` the data you need `getDataFor($el)`
3. update #1 with the results of #2 `renderBlock($el, data)`
4. insert the updated HTML into the DOM `addToContent($el)`

Code:

```
$.get("block.html", processBlock);

// create a documentFragment to fill in later
function processBlock(html) {
    var $block = $(html);
    getDataFor($block);
}

// get any needed data by querying for JSON
function getDataFor($el) {
     $.getJSON("query.php", function(data) {
         renderBlock($el, data);
     });
}

// take the data and the element and 
function renderBlock($el, data) {
    $el.find("#color").text(data.color);
    $el.find("#size").text(data.size);
    addToContent($el);
}

function addToContent($el) {
    $el.appendTo($("#content"));
}
```

In non-jquery land you're creating something called a documentFragment which lets you create a little bit a DOM you manipulate before inserting it into the page.

Simpler fiddle version:
http://jsfiddle.net/9kLzP/